# How do you convert SVG to Bitmap from a URI using Android+Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, svg, bitmap

I am currently attempting to create a bitmap using the URI of an SVG. Is this possible?

```
val bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(svgPath)
```

returns null where svgPath is the path of the SVG.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the image transformed into the Android VectorDrawable format somehow, then [Drawable.toBitmap](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/graphics/drawable/package-summary#(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable).toBitmap(kotlin.Int,%20kotlin.Int,%20android.graphics.Bitmap.Config)) takes care of rendering it... But I haven't found anything that would let you do that transformation programmatically.

If you need to handle SVGs "in the wild" I think something like https://bigbadaboom.github.io/androidsvg/ would let you render them.